# How to remove underline in the header of LibreOffice .docx file

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice

My problem is simple, maybe silly, but I have tried many times and cannot solve it, hope someone can help, the question is, how to remove the underline in the header of a .docx file opened in LibreOffice writer software of ubuntu, as [screen shot from my laptop showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xmrvd.png), I'm using 14.04 LTS and the default LibreOffice writer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First option is the paragraph style:
[image: paragraph style]

Second option is the header style (Click the header, click the arrow to open the menu, open "Border and Background..."):
[image: header style]

Hope it helps !